# Dlookup formula keeps giving Name Error in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm new and trying to learn access, I have created a form "InputIDJurnal" with a subform "DetJurnal" and I want my control field in the subform called "KodeAkun" to automatically returns a certain value according to a value in another control field called "NamaAkun", where it would then get the information needed from CoA table. I've inputted such expression on my Control Source in KodeAkun:

```
=IIf([NamaAkun]="";"";DLookUp("[KodeAkun]";"CoA";"[NamaAkun]='" & [Forms]![InputIDJurnal]![DetJurnal]![NamaAkun] & "'"))
```

Yet it keeps giving me #Name? error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: from the top link for #name error access: Typically you will see the #Name? error if the name of the control is also the name of a field in the record source and the Control Source begins with "=". You have a field name "Days Pending" and a control named "Days Pending"  try adding a prefix to your controls like txt and cmd. 
 otherwise your dlookup code looks ok

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss the *Form* property of the subform control:

```
=IIf([NamaAkun]="";"";DLookUp("[KodeAkun]";"CoA";"[NamaAkun]='" & [Forms]!
```

[InputIDJurnal]![DetJurnal].Form![NamaAkun] & "'"))

Also, `[NamaAkun]` most likely is *Null* when empty. If so:

```
=IIf(IsNull([NamaAkun]);Null;DLookUp("[KodeAkun]";"CoA";"[NamaAkun]='" & [Forms]!
```

[InputIDJurnal]![DetJurnal].Form![NamaAkun] & "'"))